# RPM File Naming Convention - known guidelines?

Tags: rpm, conventions

I have way too many dependencies going:

1. OS (RHEL vs CentOS vs Suse vs Ubuntu)
2. OS Version Number
3. Compiler Name and Version Number
4. Dependent Libraries and their version numbers
5. Compiler options used to build the libraries to ensure ABI compatibility

My code is mostly C++ right now, and I need to create rpms and the names should be descriptive enough. However factoring in items 1-5 is making things difficult since rpm name is becoming real large.

Do we have any known guidelines to address something like this?

Answer (score 3):

The guidelines are to fill your spec file correctly and use the name generated by rpmbuild.

1. The OS version is contained in the release tag. You can set for example the `Release` tag to `1.el6` for RHEL/CentOS. Some distributions provide a `%{dist}` macro that expands to something like `.el6`.
2. Same as first point
3. There is no convention for the compiler. You can add the name of the compiler to the name of the software, but you'll have to handle conflicts since you will able to install the same software several times.
4. Dependent librairies are generally not put in the name of the rpm. That would make a really long name. They are listed in the `Requires` tag of the spec file. For C++ programs, rpm can autodetect the dependencies and all you have to set is the `BuildRequires` tag (packages needed to build the software)
5. Same as 4., the compiler options for the libs are generally not put in the filename. However rpms should be compiled with as many enabled features as possible.

So, to answer your question, there are guidelines for the first two points, but not for the others since this is generally not needed (and they are not good ideas).

Comment: +1 I am not really sure why you would need an distribution label (called OS in the question).  I think that the `libc.so` is the important dependency.  There is typically a `cpu` portion and different distributions may have dependencies.  For example a **hard float** ARM verus a **soft float** ARM.  Some OS's may target `Pentium` class and better where as others will use `386`.  If you choose a lowest common denominator and/or use dynamic CPU identification, a single package **can** handle all; Linux also has library versioning.

Comment: @artlessnoise a distribution label is important because the dependencies can have different names or different versions or may not exist at all, things can be installed in different places, etc

Comment: I understand that.  I am just saying that making it distribution specific is easy.  **RPM** can accept depends that are *better than version x.y*.  File locations, etc can be accommodated by install rules.  A [virtual package](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html) can accommodate different RPM names.  If a *requires* doesn't exist at all, then the install will fail as it should.  The distribution may later have an update to provide the package.   It is easier to list a distribution, but it may not be needed if you use other facilities.  That is my only point.

Comment: This extra `spec` and *code* complexity should be balanced against maintaining multiple **rpms**, the original problem.  I am sure there are cases where this is near impossible.  It is easy to make multiple *rpms*, but **long term** this might not be the best solution.

Comment: @artlessnoise it's possible to use one spec file for many distributions (with conditionnal statements), but if there are differences between the distros you'll have to build different rpms from this spec file. Dependencies and file locations are set when you build the rpm, not when the rpm is installed.